# Host a VM on an Azure VM

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, azure

I have a generation 2 windows server 2012vm running on my Win 10 creator's laptop. Problem is, the VM fails every few days and won't reboot - I just get a cycle of the blue "choose an option" screen. I have to restore from backup each time which is a pain. I have run a full memory scan of the laptop using the Windows util that requires a reboot, but it found no errors.

I'd like to try hosting in Azure (perhaps the host laptop is causing the trouble) but it seems migrating gen 2 VMs to azure is not supported. Maybe another option would be to start a Win2012r2 VM in Azure then run my VM in Hyper-v of that. Does anyone know of this is supported?

Comment: have you made sure all the power management and sleep functions on the laptop are disabled? another option to try is making a new vm, and attaching a copy of the boot drive's vhd to it.

Comment: Thanks yes, I've removed all the sleep options and changed the power management on the laptop. I did just notice that "dynamic memory" was enabled, so I've disabled that and will see how it goes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your Azure question: You cannot run HyperV from an Azure VM. Virtualization within an Azure Virtual Machine is not supported.

Comment: Support is coming. The new Dv3 VMs will support nested virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

While Azure doesn't (yet) support Gen 2 VMs, [Azure Site Recovery has support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/disaster-recovery-to-azure-enhanced-and-were-listening/) for them.

> While Azure is working on adding this support natively, the ASR team
>   delivered a feature that converts Generation 2 to Generation 1 during
>   failover then converts back to Generation 2 when you failback to
>   on-premises.  We’re extremely pleased to announce the removal of
>   limitation on Generation 2 virtual machines based workloads protection
>   into Azure.

I hope this conversion can help you at this point.